# forward packets with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I would like to port forward all that enter to 10.32.43.75:80 to 10.48.5.66:80

how can I do this with iptables in 10.32.43.75?

I tried this, but didnt work:

**iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ens33 -p tcp --dport -j DNAT --to 10.48.5.66:80**

**iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.48.5.66 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your setup is that packet's source addresses remain the same. An example of the packet flow, where client is 192.168.100.100:

1. Client's packet with source 192.168.100.100 arrives to 10.32.43.75 port 80. Packet's source address is 192.168.100.100 and destination 10.32.43.75.
2. IPTables does destination NAT, changing destination to 10.48.5.66.
   Packet's source address is 192.168.100.100 and destination 10.48.5.66.
3. Packet is forwarded to 10.48.5.66. It sends a response packet to 192.168.100.100.
   Response packet's source address is 10.48.5.66 and destination address 192.168.100.100.
4. Response packet reaches the client. However, since the original packet was sent to 10.32.43.75, the source address 10.48.5.66 does not match client's expectations, therefore the packet is dropped.

The solution is to add `MASQUERADE` rule, which changes source IP address to `10.32.43.75` on port forwarded packets:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.48.5.66 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```